# Can't connect to my AWS Postgresql instance via local pgAdmin

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-vpc, pgadmin, aws-security-group

My plan is to migrate from **SQL Server** to **Postgresql**, hosted on AWS. My Postgresql DB is in a VPC and the security group attached to it has the following inbound rules:

[image]

The first one is for my EC2 instance (where my server-side application is running) to connect to the DB, and the second one is the home IP address so that I can connect to it via pgAdmin.

This is what I get (I don't know what to fill in at 'Maintenance database', so I left it at postgres.
[image]

What am I missing? I need help with this.

Comment: Did you make the RDS server publicly accessible?  For RDS, setting the security group is not enough.

Comment: Is the RDS database in a Public Subnet?

Comment: @jjanes Yes it's publicly accessible.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes indeed

Comment: Then it should work.  Maybe the IP address you entered into the SG is not the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed that for some combinations of VPN, local router, etc. the IP address the security group filled in for 'my IP' was not the one that RDS recognized as trying to connect. I found that `curl --silent ifconfig.me` returns the IP address that works the best for the security group.